"pcl::KdTreeFLANN" is extremely slow
I am using ROS2-Iron on Ubuntu 22.04 to filter points in a LiDAR point cloud from a rosbag, based on the following criteria: (1) points with intensity values below a certain threshold, and (2) points with fewer neighbors than a specified minimum number. To count the neighbors within a given radius, I am using the pcl::KdTreeFLANN library. However, when visualizing the results in RViz2, the performance is extremely slow. If I increase the radius or the minimum neighbor count for KdTreeFLANN, the point cloud filter processing becomes unresponsive. I would like to avoid downsampling the point cloud. Are there alternative methods to speed up this filtering process?
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;


class KdTreeFilterNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    KdTreeFilterNode() : Node("kdtree_filter_node")
    {
        this->declare_parameter<std::string>("kdtree/inputTopic", "/ouster_front/points");
        this->declare_parameter<double>("kdtree/radius_search",50.0);//mm 
        this->declare_parameter<int>("kdtree/minNeighbours", 3);
        this->declare_parameter<double>("intensity_threshold", 100.0);

        this->get_parameter("kdtree/inputTopic", input_topic_);
        this->get_parameter("kdtree/radius_search", radius_);
        this->get_parameter("kdtree/minNeighbours", min_neighbours_);
        this->get_parameter("intensity_threshold", intensity_threshold_);

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "The input topic is: %s", input_topic_.c_str());
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Radius search is set to: %.2f", radius_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Minimum neighbors required: %d", min_neighbours_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Intensity threshold: %.2f", intensity_threshold_);

        sub_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
            input_topic_, rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(),
            std::bind(&KdTreeFilterNode::cloud_cb, this, std::placeholders::_1));

        pub_output_points_ = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>("kdtree/output", 10);
    }

private:
    void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr cloud_msg)
    {
        // Convert ROS msg to PCL data type
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>());
        pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud_msg, *cloud);

        // KDTree for neighbor search
        pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZI> kdtree;
        kdtree.setInputCloud(cloud);
        //kdtree.setEpsilon(0.1);  // Set the epsilon for approximate nearest neighbor search


        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>());
        std::vector<int> point_idx_radius_search;
        std::vector<float> point_radius_squared_distance;

        // Iterate over all points in the cloud
        for (const auto& point : cloud->points)
        {
            // Perform radius search to find neighbors within the specified radius
            int neighbors_count = kdtree.radiusSearch(point, radius_, point_idx_radius_search, point_radius_squared_distance);

            // Apply the filter condition
            if (!(point.intensity <= intensity_threshold_ && neighbors_count < min_neighbours_))
            {
                // Keep points that do not meet the removal condition
                cloud_filtered->points.push_back(point);
            }
        }

        cloud_filtered->width = cloud_filtered->points.size();
        cloud_filtered->height = 1;
        cloud_filtered->is_dense = true;

        // Convert the filtered PCL data back to ROS message
        sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 output;
        pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_filtered, output);
        output.header = cloud_msg->header;

        // Publish the filtered point cloud
        pub_output_points_->publish(output);
    }

    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr sub_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr pub_output_points_;
    std::string input_topic_;
    double radius_;
    int min_neighbours_;
    double intensity_threshold_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<KdTreeFilterNode>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

I appreciate any help in advance.
Thanks,
Abbas
